# NoClassDefoundError while class is exist in the program

Tags: android, class, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem, When I run the following program then I found the NoClassDefaunderError, But that class is exist on this program. I didn't understand why this error through by the DVM:

The Program is:

```
package com.codecarpet.fbconnect.sample;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBDialog;
import com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBDialog.FBDialogDelegate;
import com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBFeedActivity;
import com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBLoginButton;
import com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBLoginButton.FBLoginButtonStyle;
import com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBPermissionActivity;
import com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBRequest;
import com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBRequest.FBRequestDelegate;
import com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBSession;
import com.codecarpet.fbconnect.FBSession.FBSessionDelegate;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // This application will not work until you enter your Facebook application's API key here:

    private static final String kApiKey = "<YOUR API KEY>";

    // Enter either your API secret or a callback URL (as described in documentation):
    private static final String kApiSecret = "<YOUR SECRET KEY>";
    private static final String kGetSessionProxy = null; // "<YOUR SESSION CALLBACK)>";
    private static final int PERMISSIONREQUESTCODE = 1;
    private static final int MESSAGEPUBLISHED = 2;
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private FBSession _session;
    private FBLoginButton _loginButton;
    private TextView _label;
    private Button _permissionButton;
    private Button _feedButton;
    private Handler mHandler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mHandler = new Handler();

        if (kGetSessionProxy != null) {
            _session = FBSession.getSessionForApplication_getSessionProxy(kApiKey, kGetSessionProxy, new FBSessionDelegateImpl());
        } else {
            _session = FBSession.getSessionForApplication_secret(kApiKey, kApiSecret, new FBSessionDelegateImpl());
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        _label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);
        _permissionButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.permissionButton);
        _permissionButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                askPermission();
            }
        });

        _feedButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.feedButton);
        _feedButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                publishFeed();
            }
        });

        _loginButton = (FBLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login);
        _loginButton.setStyle(FBLoginButtonStyle.FBLoginButtonStyleWide);
        _loginButton.setSession(_session);

        _session.resume(this);

    }

    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private void askPermission() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FBPermissionActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("permissions", new String[]{"publish_stream"});
        this.startActivityForResult(intent, PERMISSIONREQUESTCODE );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode){
        case PERMISSIONREQUESTCODE:
            if (resultCode == 1) 
                _permissionButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        default:
            return;
        }

    }

    private void publishFeed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, FBFeedActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("userMessagePrompt", "Example prompt");
        intent.putExtra("attachment", "{\"name\":\"Facebook Connect for Android\",\"href\":\"http://code.google.com/p/fbconnect-android/\",\"caption\":\"Caption\",\"description\":\"Description\",\"media\":[{\"type\":\"image\",\"src\":\"http://img40.yfrog.com/img40/5914/iphoneconnectbtn.jpg\",\"href\":\"http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php?tab=iphone/\"}],\"properties\":{\"another link\":{\"text\":\"Facebook home page\",\"href\":\"http://www.facebook.com\"}}}");
        this.startActivityForResult(intent, MESSAGEPUBLISHED);
    }

    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private class FBDialogDelegateImpl extends FBDialogDelegate {

        @Override
        public void didFailWithError(FBDialog dialog, Throwable error) {
            _label.setText(error.toString());
        }

    }

    private void checkPermission() {
        String fql = "select publish_stream from permissions where uid == " + String.valueOf(_session.getUid());
        Map<String, String> params = Collections.singletonMap("query", fql);
        FBRequest.requestWithDelegate(new FBHasPermissionRD()).call("facebook.fql.query", params);
    }    

    private class FBSessionDelegateImpl extends FBSessionDelegate {

        @Override
        public void session_didLogin(FBSession session, Long uid) {
            // we check if the user already has the permissions before displaying permission button
            checkPermission();

            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    _feedButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
             });

            String fql = "select uid,name from user where uid == " + session.getUid();

            Map<String, String> params = Collections.singletonMap("query", fql);
            FBRequest.requestWithDelegate(new FBRequestDelegateImpl()).call("facebook.fql.query", params);
        }



        @Override
        public void sessionDidLogout(FBSession session) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                   _label.setText("");
                   _permissionButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                   _feedButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               }
            });
        }

    }

    private class FBRequestDelegateImpl extends FBRequestDelegate {

        @Override
        public void request_didLoad(FBRequest request, Object result) {

            String name = null;

            if (result instanceof JSONArray) {
                JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) result;
                try {
                    JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    name = jo.getString("name");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            _label.setText("Logged in as " + name);
        }

        @Override
        public void request_didFailWithError(FBRequest request, Throwable error) {
            _label.setText(error.toString());
        }
    }

    private class FBHasPermissionRD extends FBRequestDelegate {

        @Override
        protected void request_didFailWithError(FBRequest request,
                Throwable error) {
            super.request_didFailWithError(request, error);
        }

        @Override
        public void request_didLoad(FBRequest request, Object result) {
            int hasPermission = 0;

            if (result instanceof JSONArray) {
                JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) result;
                try {
                    JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    hasPermission = jo.getInt("publish_stream");
                    if (hasPermission == 0)
                    {
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                _permissionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                         });
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the Error is:

```
11-22 11:33:02.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3213): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.codecarpet.fbconnect.sample.MainActivity$FBSessionDelegateImpl
11-22 11:33:02.510: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3213):     at com.codecarpet.fbconnect.sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:77)
```

Thanx in Advance...

Comment: Are you accessing the `FBSessionDelegateImpl` from any jar file. May be you are using an older version of jar. Just guessing. This could be an issue. Also check your classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the absolute path in your project. If you are unable to do this, then add the all file of facebook api, in your current project. After that clean and run it...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems your project using Jar file and not correctly added the path.